# Django templates loading issue

Tags: django

I have folder outside the djangoproject name custom_templates.I want to load only this templates from disk not from template caching. Everytime when i make changes in those templates dynamically ,template is loaded from cache not from disk.Thus iam unable to get updated  content on web page.
and my question is how to load templates from custom templates from disk in test and production servers where debug is set to False?

```
        template = loader.get_template(f'{path}/{theme_status}/html/private/base_template.html')
```

This code is used to load template but iam getting template from cache